# Created Product with only custom option in rwd?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created simple product with custom options but the option are appearing below the more view images instead of right side of main product image. How to solve that issue ?
This type of issue not coming in configurable product.

Comment: try to fix with `css` once.....

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Product in admin backend

In **Design** tab check option **Display Product Options In**

change it to `Product Info Column`